Variations for SharePoint 2019 on premise and use of Modern experience
We can not found any information about the following:
We'd like to create a site with 2 other languages by the use of variations. The feature is available for Team websites under SP 2019 on premise. However - can we use its functionality for pages in the Modern experience of 2019 on prem?
Is there any information available on a Microsoft URL?
Thank you very much for any help and explanation.

Dikesh, thank you for the correct english!

The variations feature in SharePoint 2019 is supported for sites created with Publishing site templates or where the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature is activated. However, the variations feature is deprecated in SharePoint Server 2019, and it is recommended to use the modern multilingual sites and pages feature instead for modern communication sites.
The modern experience in SharePoint allows for a multilingual experience where user interface elements and content can be shown in the user's preferred language, but it does not utilize the variations feature in the same way as classic publishing sites. Instead, it creates corresponding pages in the same site, organized in language-specific folders.
For your requirement of creating a site with multiple languages using variations, it is important to note that while you can use variations on Team sites, the modern experience does not support the variations feature in the same manner.
References:
Variations overview in SharePoint Server
Guide to the modern experience in SharePoint
Plan for multilingual sites in SharePoint Server

Thank you very much. All this informations was known. The new technique without variations is not available for Sharepoint 2019 ON PREM. And it seems indeed that the Modern experience does not support variations. Just, we do not find this "non supported" on a Microsoft support page...
